# How to switch user from a command line

Tags: windows, command-line

XP, Vista or Windows 7:

Is there a command to use the "switch user" feature, the same way there is one to lock the workstation?

Answer (score 18):

> Is there a command to use the "switch user" feature,

You can connect to an existing session with **`tscon`**.

---

> What I'd like to do is get to the "welcome screen",

Use **`tsdiscon`**.

If Fast User Switching is on, then simply locking the workstation`*` should display the Welcome Screen too.

*`*` I hope you don't use [rundll32](https://web.archive.org/web/20190118140536/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) LockWorkStation.*

Comment: Sorry about the delay. TSDISCON suits my purpose.

Comment: Then choose that as answer :)

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that *this works when not using RDP*, even if the documentation doesn't give hints in that direction.

Comment: tscon works even via RDP, only tsdiscon won't return you to the login screen.

Comment: @Bowi do you mean that *this doesn't work when using RDP* instead?

Comment: @Matthieu No. As far as I remember, the documentation of `tsdiscon` says *use this to disconnect from a rdp session*. So my comment is a hint to anyone else who 1) reads this answer 2) reads tsdiscon documentation and 3) says *Hey, this answer is wrong, tsdiscon can only be used when using RDP!*.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is possible, [this article](http://lifehacker.com/290435/switch-user-accounts-from-the-command-prompt) from Lifehacker explains how:

```
runas /user:*computer name\*account name explorer.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only opens an Explorer window under the context of another user. I've used it many times. What I'd like to do is get to the "welcome screen", or even downright open a session under the other user's ID, with a single command (which I'd put in a shorcut in the quick-load toolbar).

Comment: `*computer name\*` is unneccessary.

Comment: "computername" is necessary to access another computer. about launching explorer, it is only 50% of the path...

Comment: @kokbira Then Sam152 should change his answer to stipulate that is it unnecessary unless you are trying to run an instance of explorer.exe in the context of another account existing on another PC, though I note that the OP didn't state he wanted to do this with an account from another PC, in fact he didn't request anything to do with another instance of explorer.exe.

Comment: ok, but I'm talking about killing explorer before running it as another user. doing as @sam152 said will open only a new explorer window

Comment: this only works in XP

Comment: And `runas` will prompt for a password, so you can't use it in scripts. Use [`PsExec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) instead if you can.

Comment: This will open only the explorer.exe and not switching the user.