# How to switch users on Windows 8 (Non-pro edition) using the Command Prompt or 3rd-party software

Tags: windows-8, command-line, user-switching

What I need to do is to find a way to switch users **automatically** right after the main user account has logged in (when Windows 8 start-up process is over). The sequence should be like this: booting the OS -> logging into the main user account -> logging it off -> logging into another user account.

Since the edition of the OS is non-pro I cannot use scripts involving Group Policies Editor nor can I resort to the commands provided by 'quser' which is missing. From my understanding, 'Tscon' allows to switch to a user who's already logged in, and 'tsdiscon' just gets me to the Logon Screen.

If there's no other way to switch users via the Command Prompt what 3rd party software would you recommend that's capable of switching users and has a CLI so that I could use it with Windows Task Scheduler?

(Have been looking into the problem for three hours.. to no avail)

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: David, relogging/switching users seems to be the simplest workaround for a major problem of unknown origin. After the first login the system has what I would call 'a sticky Alt-button' which can be fixed by switching users or logging into the same account. No settings/system updates revert options are available

Comment: So why not ask a question about the "sticky Alt-button" and see if that can be fixed properly?

Comment: I tried Safe mode, clean boot (disabling non-system and secondary system services), uninstalling software, etc. Searched for similar discussions on the web. It appears the only proper way to fix it is a clean OS reinstall

Comment: It could be something with the keyboard or drivers. Assuming its a USB keyboard. Have you tried plugging it into a different USB port, so it gets reinstalled?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an ultrabook, so the keyboard cannot be unplugged

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch user from a command line](https://superuser.com/questions/130400/how-to-switch-user-from-a-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut to "tsdiscon.exe". Then point your Scheduled Task to this.

It works in Windows 10 (non-Pro), and a similar answer works for XP, Vista and 7.