# How to switch users in Windows 10 via the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I want to know how I can switch between multiple users on Windows 10 via the command line. I tried following:

```
runas /user:<computername>\<username> explorer.exe
```

Then I entered my password. I have actually found this solution everywhere, without an alternative. But sadly it doesn't work. It opens only one explorer in the current user account. I have admittedly not controlled the process, but under some circumstances this process is started by the other user. However, I do not switch to the other user account.

I also tried to enter the password directly with:

```
echo <password>| runas /user:<computername>\<username> explorer.exe
```

I thought the same thing would happen. But unfortunately it does not take the password. A RUNAS error appears:

```
RUNAS ERROR: explorer.exe cannot be executed.
1326: The username or password is incorrect.
```

Comment: RunAs does not switch users, it simply runs a program under a different user account.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/130508/1482432 (haven't tested it)

Comment: AFAIK, Windows doesn't support this in the way this question is worded _(a multitude of searches of Microsoft Docs returned no relevant material)_. Windows' log in/log out isn't like BSD/Linux - in order to switch to a different user, the other user's User Profile must be loaded, while the previous user's is locked/logged out. `runas` simply allows executing specific commands as another user _(keep in mind `explorer.exe` will operate differently than other executables, as it's both the Windows Shell as well as the file explorer - if no `explorer.exe` is running, the Windows Shell is started)_

Comment: So if I understand it right it is impossible? With `tsdiscon` I can logout from the current user. But I can not login to a new user. If the other user is logged in I can get the session id with `QUser`, `query user` or `QWINSTA`. But I can not login using the session id and the password.

Comment: @Micha93 AFAIK, and as mentioned above, Windows' login doesn't work in that way due to the loading/unloading of the User Profile. You could do so in a terminal via SSH, since the User Profile is removed from that equation, but not within the GUI AFAIK. For a more thorough understanding, multiple articles on [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=%22switch%20user%22%20OR%20%22user%20switching%22&scope=Desktop) may need to be read, as I searched multiple terms relating to this _(incl. W/ Powershell)_ and couldn't find relevant data, likely meaning it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows will only allow one instance of Explorer to run in the current desktop. If you run Task Manager then use the `runas` command you'll see that a second instance of `explorer.exe` is not started:

[image: Explorer]

This is specific to Explorer not a limitation of the `runas` command. A workaround is to use a different file management program. I ran into exactly the same program and got round it by using the good old File Manager app from versions of Windows older than NT4. This is now [available on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/winfile).

[image: File Manager]